# Lagrangian density for the electromagnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism

I want to know how the Lagrangian density for the electromagnetic field is written in the following form: [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Arriving at the Lagrangian Density**

The Maxwell Lagrangian density in terms of the field-strength tensor $F_{\mu\nu}$ (which has the interpretation of the curvatature of a $U(1)$ connection) is given by,

$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} = -\frac{1}{4}\left( \partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu \right)\left( \partial^\mu A^\nu -\partial^\nu A^\mu \right)$$

To arrive at your form of the Lagrangian density, simply use the explicit relation to the $E$ and $B$ fields,

$$F_{\mu\nu} = \left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
0 && -E_x && -E_y && -E_z \\
-E_x && 0 && -B_z && B_y \\
-E_y && B_z && 0 && -B_x \\
-E_z && -B_y && -B_x && 0
\end{array}
\right)$$

(Note: all expressions are written in terms of natural units.) Arriving at $\mathcal{L}$ itself requires some preliminaries in Lie group theory, and quantum field theory - see Peskin and Schroeder's text for a derivation.

---

**Addressing Lagrangian and Lagrangian density confusion**

The Lagrangian density is $\mathcal{L}$, and integrating over all space yields the Lagrangian,

$$L = \int d^dx \, \mathcal{L}$$

The action is given by the integral over time of the Lagrangian, hence,

$$S = \int dt \, L = \int d^d x \, dt \, \mathcal{L}$$

In your case, the top equation is the Lagrangian, and the bottom is the Lagrangian density. In field theory, we only really care about the action $S$ and Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L}$, and so we often call what would be the Lagrangian density as simply the Lagrangian.

Comment: thanks a lot JamalS, it helped me.
you know, the equations are from the book "Many Body Theory of Solids" by John C.Inkson (1984), chapter 3.4 "quantization of the electromagnetic field".
in fact, i wanted to know how he has written it. can you address me a text that has the derivation of the Lagrangian, please?

Comment: in fact, i want to know the relation between this lagrangian and the general form of L=T-V. here, which one is T and which one is V and why??!